# Angular4 - Remove a page reference from pages history stack

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In my angular web application need to remove a page reference from angular page history stack . Ex : i navigate from login page to dashboard page now should remove login page reference from stack.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to look in to https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#replaceUrl

You need to pass `replaceUrl: true` when navigating to component, as per doc:

```
Navigates while replacing the current state in history.

// Navigate to /view
this.router.navigate(['/view'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove all the pages stored in routeHistroy?

Comment: @MiteshShah what is your use case? Try to ask a new question.

Comment: My use case is: I have started from Page_1 and sequentially moved till Page_5. 

Now I want to go to Page_2 by removing Page_3, 4, & 5 from history. By using your code, it will just remove Page_5 from history.